# open terminal for issuing one command

Tags: linux, bash, terminal

In order to start gui-programs with parameters, I often find myself opening a terminal (in my case urxvt): starting the corresponding program with 'nohup' or 'disown', and then exiting the terminal. This keeps the program running as desired, but is not too comfortable. I do not use any multiplexer like tmux or screen, this would circumvent this problem. I would like to be able to start a terminal, which would automatically disown and exit after one command was issued. Any ideas how this can be achieved?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you ever considered using small .sh scripts as "shortcuts" to these programs?  That way you could pass in the params and exit the terminal without the typing?  Maybe not what you're looking for, but it's an idea.

Comment: thanks for the hint, but still I would need to exit the bash. This is rather cumbersome, as my window manager automatically focuses the newly created window of the started program.

or is there a possibility to close the embedding terminal from within a bash script? or telling the terminal to exit, when a program returned some exitcode?

Comment: What distribution are you using? You may already have a launcher-type program that just takes a command line and executes it, without the need to open a full-blown terminal emulator.

Comment: I am using ubuntu 12.04. As a window manager I use i3. Normally, when I want to start an x-application I use dmenu, which lists all my installed applications and supports autocompletion.

But when I need to give additional parameters to the program I would like to keep having autocompletion for files and (partially) for parameters. This is offered on the command-line, but I am not aware of any launcher-type programs, that can do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are more elegant ways of solving this problem, but here's a solution based on what you've described:

$ (xclock &); exit

Replace xclock with the GUI program you want to run.

Comment: This is okay when I want to exit the terminal after exiting the application. But I would like to exit the terminal after typing the corresponding command, and leave the terminal session before the application even exits.

Comment: Actually no. This will cause the application to start and the terminal session exits immediately. (Because of the parens.) Did you try it and it didn't work?

Comment: you are right. sorry, I do not know what I have tested, but this actually works. Thank you! So, I see the brackets change the behaviour after closing the embedding terminal, but what excactly are they doing so that the child process does not receive a signal to stop? This saves me some steps but still: I would actually like some mechanism which would prompt me with a new terminal window where I can type in my desired command (e.g. xclock in the example), and which in turn would translate it into the command you provided.

Comment: ok, the brackets seem to work like an implicit disown, as the process is removed from the list of jobs.

Comment: The parens create a subshell.